# Why is my forms clean method not doing anything?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have two basic models that use model forms in the Django admin.
Models.py is similar to:

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    url = URLField()
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel)
    ##Other fields that show up fine and save fine, but include some localflavor
```

Forms.py looks similar to:

```
class FirstModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        #call the super as per django docs
        cleaned_data = super(FirstModelForm, self).clean()
        print cleaned_data
    class Meta:
        model = FirstModel
#other modelform is the same with the appropriate word substitutions and one field that gets overridden to a USZipCodeField
```

These are a stacked inline ModelAdmin with nothing special in the admin.py:

```
class OtherModelInline(admin.StackedInline):

    model = OtherModel
    fields = (#my list of fields works correctly)
    readonly_fields = (#couple read onlys that work correctly)

class FirstModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        OtherModelInline,
        ]
admin.site.register(FirstModel, FirstModelAdmin)
```

I do have a User model, form and ModelAdmin that subclasses the User and UserCreationForm and overrides it's own clean method.This works exactly as expected.
The problem is with `FirstModel` and `OtherModel`. The clean methods I override in the ModelForm subclasses of `FirstModelForm` and `OtherModelForm` don't do anything.  No exception thrown or a print of the cleaned_data. Just nothing.  Everything else works as expected, but it's like my clean method isn't even there.
I got to be missing something simple, but I can't see what is.  Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Django dynamically generates a model form for your model admins. You must specify that you want to use your custom forms by setting the form attribute.

```
class OtherModelInline(admin.StackedInline):

    model = OtherModel
    fields = (...) # if this doesn't work after specifying the form, set fields for the model form instead
    readonly_fields = (#couple read onlys that work correctly)
    form = OtherModelForm

class FirstModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FirstModelForm
    inlines = [
        OtherModelInline,
        ]
admin.site.register(FirstModel, FirstModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what it was and I should have known because I assigned the form in my User ModelAdmin.  I knew it was something simple, I just suffer from severe functional fixedness at times.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `cleaned_data` from the `clean` method in the form. If you look at [the documentation for cleaning fields that rely on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) you'll notice:

```
...
# Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
return cleaned_data
```

Comment: I see.  Thanks, but this wouldn't cause my clean method to not do anything.  There should still be a print out to the console of my `cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that nothing survived the parent 'clean' method. If you are submitting data that won't validate because of the way your models are set up, cleaned_data will be empty. This is mentioned in the same doc linked by Timmy, where it says:

> By the time the form’s clean() method is called, all the individual field clean methods will have been run (the previous two sections), so self.cleaned_data will be populated with any data that has survived so far. **So you also need to remember to allow for the fact that the fields you are wanting to validate might not have survived the initial individual field checks.**

In this case, if you have a URLField, the field validation is very strict, and unless you define 'verify_exists=False', it will also check if you are putting in a URL that returns a 404. In your case you would need to do this if you wanted to allow that:

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    url = URLField(verify_exists=False)
```

Outside of that, I have no idea what could be going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not what I was looking for.  Although I wasn't aware of the `verify_exists` parameter, I am now.

Comment: No problem, glad someone got you sorted. I haven't used the built in admin for several years now :)